# How to check the first date an app is installed?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have a paid app and want to offer it as free for a few days in the Store. But only for those who installed it during these special days I want to show ads.

How can I check if a user installed the app in a specific time range?

**I thought of these solutions:**

- I could have a sign in previous packages and check it in this
  package. if it was not available this was the first install.
- I could save the date after installation since the first time.

But these won't work now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [get App receipt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentApp_GetAppReceiptAsync) from the store ([here is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases) how it can look like) and parse the *PurchaseDate* of your product. However this will return the date when the app has been first installed, if the user has reinstalled the app, then it will return the date of the very first installation (first 'purchase' from the store).

You can also have a value in *LocalSettings* that will be responsible for remembering the date of first run of the app. But this doesn't mean the date of installation - user can install the app and run it after a month. Also when user reinstalls the app, you will get the new value.

Comment: Thanks @Romasz for your answer. as a note for the second option, if I remember correctly, we can run a background task right after the app is installed, without requiring the use actually run it. I'll go with the first option. thanks.

Comment: @Blendester AFAIK it's not possible to run background task without running and registering the app first, there is something like UpdateTrigger, but for this user also has to run the app at least once (I think).

Comment: @Blendester And before going to production, check this on beta version of the app published to the store - if it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows collection API to scope your query to your particular product (app or add-on). After sending request, you will receive a response including an array item `CollectionItemContractV6` which contains the parameters like `acquireDate` and some others which you're likely to use. Then you can unlock the feature to the user who installed your app within the correct time range.

You may follow the steps below to use this API:

> 1. [Configure a Web application in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-1).
> 2. [Associate your Azure AD client ID with your application in the
>      Windows Dev Center dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-2).
> 3. In your service, [create Azure AD access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-3) that represent your
>      publisher identity.
> 4. In client-side code in your Windows app, [create a Windows Store ID
>      key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-4) that represents the identity of the current user, and pass the
>      Windows Store ID key back to your service.
> 5. After you have the required Azure AD access token and Windows Store
>      ID key, [call the Windows Store collection API or purchase API from
>      your service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-5).

For more details, you could check **[Query for products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/query-for-products#response)** which includes both the request and response sample.

Comment: Isn't this only for apps associated with Azure? (`customer owns for apps that are associated with your Azure AD client ID`)

Comment: It just requires you to have an Azure Active Directory(Azure AD) directory and you must have Global administrator permission for the directory, since this API uses **Azure AD authentication** to access customer ownership information. For specific steps, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#overview).