# Get UWP app acquisition date

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

How can I get an app's acquisition date?

I tried using `StoreContext` - `ExtendedJsonData()` but it didn't have that information.

Comment: You may take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42500510/2681948), however it will return the date of first acquisition, even if the user has installed/reinstalled the app couple of times.

Comment: @Romasz Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I was checking the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace because it is the new one, and more future-proof. +1 for your answer there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the first date an app is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500510/how-to-check-the-first-date-an-app-is-installed)

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, this is been a question many UWP devs have asked.

Answer (score 1):

Many UWP devs have asked about this and it's true... you can't ask for this value. You can only get the purchase or first-time download date.

However, you can try this trick. It's just a workaround, so don't blame me if one day it fails you :)

```
var properties = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
var installationDate = properties.ItemDate; // Maybe?
```

Let me know if it works for you.